# How do I achieve this in C#

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do I aggregate conditionally in C#

Like in the following vb code:

```
Dim movement = From item In dbo.VIEWITEMMOVEMENTs
               Where item.DATETRANSFERRED.Value.Date = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
               Group By item.DATETRANSFERRED.Value.Date, item.ITEMDESCRIPTION
               Into moved = Group, sold = Sum(item.QUANTITYSOLD), [IN] = Sum(If(item.QUANTITY < 0.0, 0.0, item.QUANTITY)), Out = Sum(If(item.QUANTITY > 0, 0, item.QUANTITY))
               Select ITEMDESCRIPTION, sold, [IN], Out Order By ITEMDESCRIPTION Ascending
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = movement
```

Comment: What did you try? The C# is virtually identical.

Comment: This sort of question isn't really a good fit for this site.  The subject line is of little use, too - it's search-proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var result = (
                from item in dbo.VIEWITEMMOVEMENTs
                where item.DATETRANSFERRED.Value.Date == this.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
                group item by new { item.DATETRANSFERRED.Value.Date, item.ITEMDESCRIPTION }
                into g
                select new
                {
                    g.Key.ITEMDESCRIPTION,
                    sold = g.Sum(x => x.QUANTITYSOLD),
                    IN = g.Sum(x => (x.QUANTITY <0 ? 0 : x.QUANTITY)),
                    Out = g.Sum(x => (x.QUANTITY > 0 ? 0 : x.QUANTITY))
                }
               ).OrderBy(d => d.ITEMDESCRIPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to convert that snippet of code. you could use the converters like

[**VB to C#**](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Hope this helps.